# Is it possible to run an Apollo model as a function? - gives errors about global environment

Tags: r, function

Let's say I have this Apollo model (from http://www.apollochoicemodelling.com/files/examples/4%20Ranking%20and%20rating/OL.r)

```
# ################################################################# #
#### LOAD LIBRARY AND DEFINE CORE SETTINGS                       ####
# ################################################################# #

### Clear memory
rm(list = ls())

### Load Apollo library
library(apollo)

### Initialise code
apollo_initialise()

### Set core controls
apollo_control = list(
  modelName       = "OL",
  modelDescr      = "Ordered logit model fitted to attitudinal question in drug choice data",
  indivID         = "ID", 
  outputDirectory = "output"
)

# ################################################################# #
#### LOAD DATA AND APPLY ANY TRANSFORMATIONS                     ####
# ################################################################# #

### Loading data from package
### if data is to be loaded from a file (e.g. called data.csv), 
### the code would be: database = read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE)
database = ?apollo_drugChoiceData
### for data dictionary, use ?apollo_drugChoiceData

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE MODEL PARAMETERS                                     ####
# ################################################################# #

### Vector of parameters, including any that are kept fixed in estimation
apollo_beta = c(beta_reg_user   = 0, 
                beta_university = 0, 
                beta_age_50     = 0, 
                tau_quality_1   =-2, 
                tau_quality_2   =-1, 
                tau_quality_3   = 1, 
                tau_quality_4   = 2)

### Vector with names (in quotes) of parameters to be kept fixed at their starting value in apollo_beta, use apollo_beta_fixed = c() if none
apollo_fixed = c()

# ################################################################# #
#### GROUP AND VALIDATE INPUTS                                   ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE MODEL AND LIKELIHOOD FUNCTION                        ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_probabilities=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs, functionality="estimate"){
    
  ### Attach inputs and detach after function exit
  apollo_attach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs)
  on.exit(apollo_detach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs))

  ### Create list of probabilities P
  P = list()
  
  ### Calculate probabilities using Ordered Logit model
  ol_settings = list(outcomeOrdered = attitude_quality, 
                     utility        = beta_reg_user*regular_user + beta_university*university_educated + beta_age_50*over_50, 
                     tau            = list(tau_quality_1, tau_quality_2, tau_quality_3, tau_quality_4),
                     rows           = (task==1))
  
  P[["model"]] = apollo_ol(ol_settings, functionality)
  
  ### Take product across observation for same individual
  P = apollo_panelProd(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)

  ### Prepare and return outputs of function
  P = apollo_prepareProb(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  return(P)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL ESTIMATION                                            ####
# ################################################################# #

model = apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL OUTPUTS                                               ####
# ################################################################# #

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO SCREEN)                               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_modelOutput(model)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO FILE, using model name)               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_saveOutput(model)
```

However, since I need to make many version of the same model with a very small change, I would love to make it into a function. Say like this:

```
Apollofunction <- function(beta,variable){
      # ################################################################# #
    #### LOAD LIBRARY AND DEFINE CORE SETTINGS                       ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    ### Clear memory
    rm(list = ls())
    
    ### Load Apollo library
    library(apollo)
    
    ### Initialise code
    apollo_initialise()
    
    ### Set core controls
    apollo_control = list(
      modelName       = "OL",
      modelDescr      = "Ordered logit model fitted to attitudinal question in drug choice data",
      indivID         = "ID", 
      outputDirectory = "output"
    )
    
    # ################################################################# #
    #### LOAD DATA AND APPLY ANY TRANSFORMATIONS                     ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    ### Loading data from package
    ### if data is to be loaded from a file (e.g. called data.csv), 
    ### the code would be: database = read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE)
    database = ?apollo_drugChoiceData
    ### for data dictionary, use ?apollo_drugChoiceData
    
    # ################################################################# #
    #### DEFINE MODEL PARAMETERS                                     ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    ### Vector of parameters, including any that are kept fixed in estimation
    apollo_beta = c(beta            = 0, 
                    beta_university = 0, 
                    beta_age_50     = 0, 
                    tau_quality_1   =-2, 
                    tau_quality_2   =-1, 
                    tau_quality_3   = 1, 
                    tau_quality_4   = 2)
    
    ### Vector with names (in quotes) of parameters to be kept fixed at their starting value in apollo_beta, use apollo_beta_fixed = c() if none
    apollo_fixed = c()
    
    # ################################################################# #
    #### GROUP AND VALIDATE INPUTS                                   ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()
    
    # ################################################################# #
    #### DEFINE MODEL AND LIKELIHOOD FUNCTION                        ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    apollo_probabilities=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs, functionality="estimate"){
        
      ### Attach inputs and detach after function exit
      apollo_attach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs)
      on.exit(apollo_detach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs))
    
      ### Create list of probabilities P
      P = list()
      
      ### Calculate probabilities using Ordered Logit model
      ol_settings = list(outcomeOrdered = attitude_quality, 
                         utility        = beta*variable + beta_university*university_educated + beta_age_50*over_50, 
                         tau            = list(tau_quality_1, tau_quality_2, tau_quality_3, tau_quality_4),
                         rows           = (task==1))
      
      P[["model"]] = apollo_ol(ol_settings, functionality)
      
      ### Take product across observation for same individual
      P = apollo_panelProd(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
    
      ### Prepare and return outputs of function
      P = apollo_prepareProb(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
      return(P)
    }
    
    # ################################################################# #
    #### MODEL ESTIMATION                                            ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    model = apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)
    
    # ################################################################# #
    #### MODEL OUTPUTS                                               ####
    # ################################################################# #
    
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
    #---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO SCREEN)                               ----
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
    
    apollo_modelOutput(model)
    
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
    #---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO FILE, using model name)               ----
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
    
    apollo_saveOutput(model)
  }
```

Then I could be able to call this apollo function with multiple variations:

```
Apollofunction(beta_reg_user, regular_user)
Apollofunction(etc, etc)
```

However, when I then try to run the function, it gives me the error `Error in apollo_validateInputs() :  No variable called database found in user workspace (i.e. global environment).`

I then tried to upload the database in the global environment and delete the `rm(list = ls())`, but then I just get this error: `Error in apollo_validateInputs() :  No variable called apollo_beta found in user workspace (i.e. global environment).` - so there seems to be a problem with how the function interacts with the global environment. Any way to change that? Maybe it has something to do with the use of "="?

The data is available at the link for OL - the csv file. http://www.apollochoicemodelling.com/examples.html

[image]

Comment: A function would automatically try and search the global environment if it doesn't exist in the function namespace. So I doubt that it's how the function interacts with the global environment. I tried running `database = ?apollo_drugChoiceData` and I think that was just meant to be a placeholder. It just calls the help file.

Comment: In my actual code, I just use read_csv, so that can't be the reason. Thank you for the explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: It's going to be tough to fully reproduce these errors unless we have your code in a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: The data is an example dataset publicly available. For some reason I thought that it was already built into rstudio. But it is found on the website I linked in the bottom.